# Ghost CMS navigation goes to non-custom domain

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

I have a Ghost site at https://msclouddeveloper.com
However, the navigation links point to an azurewebsites.net address. But in the Ghost CMS the correct custom domain is shown (msclouddeveloper.com).
The websiteUrl appsetting is also set correctly.
What could be wrong? I've already restarted the app service.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I missed this when reading the setup guide for custom domains, but you need to add two AppSettings:

```
websiteUrl    http://www.msclouddeveloper.com
websiteUrlSSL https://www.msclouddeveloper.com
```

Then restart the App service.
What could also be an issue is the environment setup you have enabled. See this documentation for more info https://docs.ghost.org/docs/config 
For custom domain SSL links to work you need to have the production environment enabled. You set this in the file iis-node.yaml I believe. But it was already correct in my case.